# How to Change LLDB Version CLion Uses?

Tags: c++, c++11, lldb, clion

**TL;DR:** I want to change the version of LLDB that CLion (v2016.3.5) uses to LLDB v3.8.1. Can I do this? If so, how?

**Longer explanation of the question:**

CLion is a C++ IDE that I've been using for a few years now. Recently, they released version 2016.3.X. When they went from 2016.2 to 2016.3, they changed the "built in lldb" version from v3.8.1 to v3.9.0. This has caused a problem for me as v3.9.0 doesn't seem to want to work correctly.

When I, say, "print some_var_name" (while at a break point) I get an error (below):

> Assertion failed: (D->getCachedLinkage() == LV.getLinkage()), function
>   getLVForDecl, file
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/92515a49514b3993/lldb/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/Decl.cpp,
>   line 1360.

The source of this file can be found here: https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Decl_8cpp_source.html

My options are

(1) Figure out why that error is happening. Creating a simple "hello world"program and debugging seems to work. This tells me that it has something to do with my code base, I suppose. But I have over 20,000 lines of code. So figuring out what's doing it would be extremely time consuming. LLDB version 3.8.1 seems like a faster/easier fix since it was doing me just fine in the past.

(2) Use an old version of CLion (which, by default, utilizes LLDB version 3.8.1)

(3) Get the new(er) version(s) of CLion to use LLDB version 3.8.1.

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Comment: Can you check a newer CLion version? Website says 2017.1 is available.

Comment: I have this same issue in CLion 2017.2

Comment: FYI, I added an Issue on their tracker for this. It can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9488 There's also a sample project that produces the error and explains what I had to do to not get the error. Very odd solution that may not work in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you could just enter the path in this preferences page:

[image]

Comment: Well, that says custom "Custom GDB" so I thought that meant only for GNU Debugger. Adding "/usr/bin/lldb" (which is the location) produces the error "GDB version: unknown"